# Replace fractions to decimals in string

Tags: regex, kotlin

I need to replace fraction in given string to decimal.
So:

```
1/4 xx -> 0.25 xx
1/3 xx -> 0.33 xx
```

Above exampels I got covered with:

```
private fun String.replaceFractions() = "(?:[1-9]*)/[1-9]*".toRegex().find(this)
        ?.let {
            val fraction = it.groups[0]!!.value
            val fractionParts = fraction.split("/")
                    .map { part -> part.toDouble() }
            this.replace(fraction, (fractionParts[0] / fractionParts[1]).toString())
        }
        ?: this
```

But I cannot find a way to replace properly string when they also have whole part:

```
1 1/4 xx -> 1.25 xx
3 3/5 xx -> 3.6 xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve what you want with a mere `replace` like

```
val s = "Some text: 1/4 and 3 3/5"
val result = s.replace("""(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+)?(\d+)/(\d+)""".toRegex()) {
    ((if (it.groupValues[1].isNullOrEmpty()) 0.0 else it.groupValues[1].toDouble()) + (it.groupValues[2].toDouble() / it.groupValues[3].toDouble())).toString()
}    
println(result) // => Some text: 0.25 and 3.6
```

See [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/MRPW47993)

**Regex details**

- `(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: 1+ digits, and then 1 or 0 (optional) sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: 1+ digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: 1+ digits

If Group 1 matched, its value is cast to double, else, `0` is taken, and the value is summed with the result of Group 2 and Group 3 division.